# Extract RPM into a single fat/uber JAR?

Tags: java, maven, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin, cpio

I created an RPM using the [Maven RPM Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/).

When I try to extract the RPM USING `rpm2cpio foo.rpm | cpio -idmv`, I get multiple jars - one for the actual application and one jar for each dependency.

Is there a way for me to extract the RPM into a single fat/uber JAR?

Comment: There's probably not a way to do what you're asking just by using the RPM plugin, but you should be able to configure Maven to bundle all resources together when the project is actually packaged rather than when the RPM plugin is invoked. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven; if you need more information, update the question with further details.

Comment: I think I figured it out. My mappings for rpm-maven-plugin were `            <mapping>
              <directory>${app.home}</directory>
              <artifact/>
              <dependency/>
            </mapping>
`
The artifact already included dependencies. I just removed `<dependency/>` since I don't need it.